# ActivityNotFoundException on requestPermissions with Android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions

I get a crash at a user when calling requestPermissions on a samsung S5.
I don't understand what could be the reason?

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
       if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            MainActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
```

Here is the stack crash:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1878)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1673)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4915)
  at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions (Activity.java:4167)
  at com.narb.checknetwork.MainActivity.permissionRequest (MainActivity.java:276)
  at com.bernard_zelmans.checknetwork.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:101)
```

Added information.

I have all the permissions I require included.

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.narb.checknetwork">

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="CheckNet"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/networksafe"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: 2 years later, just got the exact same stack trace on Android 10, Moto G+. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

used below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between MainActivity.this and this?

Comment: this keyword refer to current activity and if pass particular activity name and suppose you not get that activity that time it show error activity not found.

Comment: The call to requestPermissions is in mainactivity. I admit that I am unsure why I used MainActivity.this but checking the value in debug, this and MainActivity.this have the same value. So I don't understand your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
   if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
```

One more important thing, Check whether you declared MainActivity in your  Manifest.xml or not

Comment: What is the difference between MainActivity.this and ActivityCompact? I have many users already.